# return raw soap body using HttpWebRequest

Tags: wcf, soap, httpwebrequest

I tried to send information to a service and return the raw soap body using this code.  Is it possible?

```
  DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GetInfoRequest));
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Service.svc/soap/GetDataSoap");
            GetInfoRequest message = new GetInfoRequest();
            message.data = new List<int>();
            message.data.Add(268435458);
            message.data.Add(99);

            MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.WriteObject(stream1, message);
            stream1.Position = 0;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream1);
            string t = sr.ReadToEnd();

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            request.Timeout = 99999999;
            request.ContentLength = t.Length;
            //request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: \"http://localhost/Service.svc/soap/GetDataSoap\"");
            request.Accept = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";


            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(t);
                requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
                //serializer.WriteObject(stream1, message);
                //requestStream.Flush();
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            var abc = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            TextBox1.Text = abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible this way. You are sending JSON request and expect SOAP response. That will not work. You must send valid SOAP request to your SOAP service and get SOAP response.

Comment: So when I need send SOAP request, it is some serializer which serlize my Custom class to soap request ?

Comment: Serialization has nothing to do with SOAP request. SOAP is a protocol and you must create correct SOAP request and pass serialized class as its content. The SOAP request must have all features the service expects.